# ssh hangs even after putting ServerAliveInterval 60

Tags: ssh

I was having the same problem of SSH connection hanging after some N minutes. After seeing some tutorials I come to know that one way to avoid it is, give ServerAliveInterval as 60 or any time interval, which deems suitable to you. Now the issue that it is not working. Syntax seems fine to be but just wanted to double check with guys at SF.

first, my config was not there so I created it.

```
sudo nano ~/.ssh/config 
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

I don't know what's wrong here, But it doesn't seem to work. I don't know where to start looking for issues.

Comment: Is this hanging for every SSH server you connect to, or a particular one?

Comment: Every server I connect to

Comment: This syntax is fine. Consider that some firewalls will drop idle connections to conserve resources, expecting them to be easily re-established. Stateful connections such as SSH won't survive this. Also consider that you may have bad permissions on your .ssh/config file. As an easy way to test, put the line `ServerAliveInterval 60` into the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file for global effect (to see if keepalive is working at all in your case).

Comment: After that do I have to do sudo service ssh restart?

Comment: no, because this affects the client, not the server. The ssh daemon is the server. Changes made to the client configuration take effect upon the next connection attempt.

Comment: And what should be the permissions on config file ideally

Comment: I just needs to be readable by owner and group. 0644 is typical. Let me know if that global configuration works.

Comment: I think it's working @SmallLoanOf1M. Thanks. Can you post that as an answer with the permissions thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running into ssh client problems, permissions are a typical culprit. make sure that this `.ssh/config` file is readable by user and group owners. Typical permissions for this file are 0644. The .ssh directory should be readable and browsable by user and group owner as well.

Also consider making this setting a global one by placing the following line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_conf`:

`ServerAliveInterval 60`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sudo` for random commands, then those programs will indeed look in another place for your configuration. You definitely don't need superuser permissions for editing configurations in your own user directory...

Here, `~/.ssh/` expanded to something like `/home/saras/.ssh/` in your user shell, and so that's where you made changes. If you then also `sudo ssh user@example.org`, the ssh program runs as root and will look in root's home directory at `/root/.ssh/` which does not have the configuration that you just created in your own home directory.

The difference between the commands is that the terminal runs under your own user, and your command line (bash, probably) runs with that same user, and that's what is doing shell expansion. That turns `$RANDOM` into `9` and `~/` into `/home/saras/` upon executing the command. Notice how the `ssh` command does not have the configuration location specified, so it will have to look in a place based on the user that it is being run as, which is root, rather than receiving the location after shell expansion.

Overriding the global configuration as [suggested by Spooler](https://serverfault.com/a/810110/119360) will also circumvent this problem, which it seems to have done because you've marked the answer as accepted, but this does not fix the origin of your issue.